# UDP data loss program hint in java

Tags: java, networking, udp

I'm a newbie in networking in java and i know packets may get lost in UDP protocol. I'm looking to make a program which shows the effect of UDP data loss so that the concept becomes clearer. Therefore i want hints for making a program myself which shows data loss using UDP.

Comment: If you are asking us to find a program that does this, that is "Off Topic".  If you are asking us to write one for you, that is "Too Broad" (and an abuse).  If you want hints on how to write a program yourself; see below.

Comment: i just want some hints..

Comment: I think the question is too vague/broad. You want to write a program that sends a large file over UDP, then compares how accurately it was sent ..... So what are you asking help for, exactly? I'd advise you to have a go at this yourself, then ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Just wanted some hints and got it from @StephenC .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write two programs:

- A client that sends UDP packets containing a sequence number that it keeps incrementing.
- A server program that accepts UDP packets, extracts the sequence number, and checks to see if they any are missing or out of order.  If there is no loss or reordering of packets, the server should see the UDP packets in ascending order ... as sent by the client.

Then run the client and server, with the client sending to the server.  If packets are missing, that illustrates UDP data loss.